# How can I get an NSTextField to behave like a HTML text?

Tags: cocoa, text, resize, nstextfield, autoresize

I have some static text that is usually only 1 line long that displays in a NSTextField in my xib. In some instances, the text is long enough to warrant 2 lines, and I just want the label to resize vertically to fit it, without giving me scrollers or any thing else.  Think of how text on a webpage behaves… that is what I want. I just want the label to grow shrink with different text, and with adjustments to its width. How can I achieve this?

**UPDATE**
Here is a video of how it currently behaves: http://screencast.com/t/4JYTv7jVG3O

Notice how when the `NSTextField` is two lines long, there is a big gap underneath the text. This is because the stars and button are aligned at the bottom of the frame, and because I have to have the frame taller to accommodate 2 lines, they stay there. If I can get an answer to this question, I would make the frame shorter for the 1 line text, and make the bottom textfield (with the smaller text) taller to compensate. Can this type of floating layout be done?

Comment: Can't you make the textfield's background transparent, set the field to two lines and then make the textfield two lines high? I think the text will only wrap when it hits the edge of the field... Still, if it behaved like HTML that'd be very interesting...

Comment: Yes, but I have views under it that I align with the bottom edge of the text field. If I do what you suggest, I am left with space between the text and the lower elements for the 1 line cases, and no space in the 2-line cases.  I am trying to present a uniform visual experience

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to actually use a `WebView` to display your content. You will then get exactly the behaviour you are expecting, at the cost of a bit of work to manage interaction with the controls.

You would need to set the `WebView` to display no background, using `[webView setDrawsBackground:NO]`.

You'd also need to construct the content (including the star rating and the button) using HTML/CSS and then use the Objective-C/JavaScript bridge to call back to your app when the button is pressed.

More information on calling Objective-C from JavaScript is [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/SafariJSProgTopics/Tasks/ObjCFromJavaScript.html).

You could probably also use an `NSTextView` and embed the button and star rating as `NSTextAttachment` objects but this is quite complex, it would be a lot easier to use a `WebView`.

The only other alternative that I can see is writing a view controller that manages the layout of the controls based on the current size of their container view. You would need to measure the text to do this and one way to do that is to use the excellent [NS(Attributed)String+Geometrics](http://www.sheepsystems.com/sourceCode/sourceStringGeometrics.html) category written by Jerry Krinock.

Comment: I've updated the answer with a couple of other options, but unfortunately I don't think there's an "easy" answer.